# Creating global variables for UDP client program

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, network-programming, udp

I am creating a UDP tunnel client program to receive random packets from client OS system and send the data packets to a UDP server using a reader thread function. Similarly I am reading packets from the UDP server and sending it to the client's tunnel IP address. The reader and writer threads must run simultaneously. I get the following error when I execute the program.

```
use of moved value: `socket`
value used here after moverustcE0382
basic.rs(68, 38): value moved into closure here
basic.rs(74, 21): variable moved due to use in closure
basic.rs(101, 21): use occurs due to use in closure
basic.rs(58, 9): move occurs because `socket` has type `UdpSocket`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How do I declare the socket variable as global variable to remove the error occurring at writer thread when I use the keyword move?

```
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("8.0.0.1:8000") //create client socket object with ip and port
                       .expect("Could not bind client socket");

socket.connect("8.0.0.10:8888") //SERVER IP /PORT
                      .expect("Could not connect to server");

thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5)); // PROVIDING TIME TO ESTABLISH SOCKET CONNECTION TO SERVER



let reader_session = session.clone();

let reader = std::thread::spawn( move || {
    while RUNNING.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        match reader_session.receive_blocking() {
            Ok(packet) => {                     //receiving random packets from OS
                let bytes = packet.bytes();
                let leng = bytes.len();
                socket.send(&bytes[0..leng]);     //SENDING RANDOM PACKETS TO SERVER

                println!
                (
                    "Version & IHL: {}  Service Type: {}  Packet Length: {} {}  Identification: {} {}  Flags&Fragment: {} {}  
                    TTL: {}  Protocol: {}  Checksum: {} {}  SourceIP: {}.{}.{}.{}  DestIP: {}.{}.{}.{}",
                    &bytes[0],&bytes[1],&bytes[2],&bytes[3],&bytes[4],&bytes[5],&bytes[6],&bytes[7],
                    &bytes[8],&bytes[9],&bytes[10],&bytes[11],
                    &bytes[12],&bytes[13],&bytes[14],&bytes[15],&bytes[16],&bytes[17],&bytes[18],&bytes[19]
                );
                println!();
                
            }
            
            Err(_) => println!("Got error while reading packet"),
        }
    }
});


 
let writer_session = session.clone();
let writer_socket = socket.try_clone()?;
let writer = std::thread::spawn(move || {
    info!("Starting writer");

while RUNNING.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        let mut buffer = [0u8; 1500]; 
                writer_socket.recv_from(&mut buffer) //get message from server
                     .expect("Could not read into buffer");
        let mut leng1 = buffer.len();


                println!("From server: {}", str::from_utf8(&buffer) //print message from server
                     .expect("Could not write buffer as string"));
                     socket.send_to(&buffer[0..leng1],"6.0.0.1"); //send message from server to tunnel ip
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to clone the `UdpSocket` using the `try_clone()` method which creates a new variable referencing the same underlying socket.

e.g.

```rust
...
let reader_session = session.clone();
let reader_socket = socket.try_clone().expect("Couldn't clone the socket");

let reader = std::thread::spawn( move || {
...
       reader_socket.send(&bytes[0..leng]);
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.try_clone

Comment: I get the following error when I change my code according to your suggestion. What could be the reason.                                                                                      the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, std::io::Error>>` is not implemented for `()`rustcE0277
basic.rs(18, 1): this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`

Comment: I have edited the writer thread in the above code. please do let me know why the error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. `?` only works if the function returns a `Result` as it propagates the the error that might occur. Switching it to `expect()`will work but introduces the possibility of a panic if something fails.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile in itself so I can't say for sure but I suspect you might need to move the clone to before the reader section. As soon as you create the reader thread you are passing ownership of `socket` to the thread and so it shouldn't be available to clone after.